# Receive Json sent from Angular to Laravel

Tags: json, angular, laravel

I'm trying to send a json to the backend, here is the piece of code that I use to send data:

```
register(user): Observable<any>{
        let json = JSON.stringify(user);
        let params = 'json='+json;

        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        console.log(json);
        console.log(params);
        console.log(headers);

        return this._http.post('http://api-rest-laravel.com.devel/api/register', params, {headers: headers});
    }
```

This is the code in the backend:

```
     public function register(Request $request) {
    
            Log::info("Datos: " . $request);
            $json = $request->input('json', null);
            $params = json_decode($json);
            $params_array = json_decode($json, true); //Array
            Log::info("Json: " . $json);
            if (!empty($params) && !empty($params_array)) {
                //register
            }else{
                //send error msg
            }
```

If i try the backend using Postman, this is what i get from Request param:

```
[2020-10-04 15:37:36] local.INFO: Datos: POST /api/register HTTP/1.1
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  229
Content-Type:    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:          laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InoxMG53RXZTTGZaV0h3dFF6VmVDUXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZ2V6ZEFYNjZKOSt0K0RPMmgra0FCMVUwMkhIb0JGSjJ6cW53VkhKSnUwV1ViWENVZTNDaXl3UzlBckZVYXRCSSIsIm1hYyI6ImM2YzA0MjEzYzRjMTEzNmQxYmY4NTJmNDRhNzk1ZGJmZGQwOGU2NmQ2NDM5OWM2MDcwNjFjNmJiMTIzNDIyM2MifQ%3D%3D
Host:            api-rest-laravel.com.devel
Postman-Token:   47cfbc5a-136c-424d-9e1b-f61c18c2fc5c
User-Agent:      PostmanRuntime/7.26.5
Cookie: laravel_session=pi7VHwGsyzTB36rK7KdbtAUU4GGagUNSklMQliqL


json=%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22qwer%22%2C%22surname%22%3A%22qwe%22%2C%22role%22%3A%22ROLE_USER%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22qqwer22%40asd.com%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22qqq%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%22%2C%22image%22%3A%22%22%7D  
[2020-10-04 15:37:36] local.INFO: Json: {"id":1,"name":"qwer","surname":"qwe","role":"ROLE_USER","email":"qqwer22@asd.com","password":"qqq","description":"","image":""}  
[2020-10-04 15:37:36] local.INFO: goes toIF
```

and this is request param if I try it in browser ($json is empty, second last line):

```
[2020-10-04 15:40:30] local.INFO: Datos: POST /api/register HTTP/1.1
Accept:          application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  127
Content-Type:    aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
Dnt:             1
Host:            api-rest-laravel.com.devel
Origin:          http://localhost:4200
Referer:         http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36

json={"id":1,"name":"qwe","surname":"qwe","role":"ROLE_USER","email":"qqwe@asd.com","password":"q","description":"","image":""}  
[2020-10-04 15:40:30] local.INFO: Json:   
[2020-10-04 15:40:30] local.INFO: goes to ELSE
```

I also tried to send from frontend a json simillar to the one sent from postman to see if that was the problem. Didn't work.

```
//return this._http.post('http://api-rest-laravel.com.devel/api/register', 'json=%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22qwer%22%2C%22surname%22%3A%22qwe%22%2C%22role%22%3A%22ROLE_USER%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22qqwer222%40asd.com%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22qqq%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%22%2C%22image%22%3A%22%22%7D', {headers: headers});
```

Why is this happening? I'm newbie with angular and laravel and I didnt find a solution so far. Corse is OK

Comment: You don’t have to stringify user on the angular side, angular already does that for you. You can straight away pass user to the post and then on the server side read the request body.

Comment: oh thanks a lot, I didnt know that. That was enough for me to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

in your header :

- `let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')`